# woocommerce hook on page-new.php

Tags: forms, woocommerce, hook, action

I'm using woocommerce and mgates vendor software while adding hooks on the page-new.php page to make instructions for my vendors on the add product page. I'm using

```
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_after_title' ); 
function myprefix_edit_form_after_title() { 
    echo 'This is my text!';
}
```

as well as after editor and form advanced

On my add product page I have:

Title

```
'edit_form_after_title'
```

Description

```
'edit_form_after_editor'
```

Product Short Description

- How do I figure out what hook to put between these to sections?

Product Data

---

How or where would I put these hooks to have them only get them to show up on the Add Products post page and not ever post page?

Answer (score 0):

You can fire your hook selectively using:

```php
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'your_callback' );
```

And then check for the post type before adding the hook:

```php
function your_callback()
{
    global $typenow;
    if( 'product' != $typenow ) 
        return;

    add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_after_title' ); 
}
```

Or, another option:

```php
add_action( 'edit_form_after_title', 'myprefix_edit_form_after_title' ); 

function myprefix_edit_form_after_title() 
{ 
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if( 'post-new.php' != $pagenow || 'product' != $typenow )
        return;

    echo 'This is my text!';
}
```